# Google Apps Script and Google Fusion Tables. Invalid Credentials

Tags: google-apps-script, google-fusion-tables

I'm trying to add a row of data to a Fusion Table. Having trouble with OAuth it seems. I go through requesting for a token and receive one and store it. This is the code used to do this:

```
var AUTHORIZE_URL = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth';

function getURLForAuth(){
 return AUTHORIZE_URL + '?response_type=code&client_id='+CLIENT_ID+'&redirect_uri='+REDIRECT_URL +'&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables&state=/profile';  
}
```

After allowing access on the google site page this code gives me a page from which I can take the token and store it. I then try to use this token to insert a few values into a table with this code:

```
 function _submitLog(e){
 var rowToAdd = [e.parameter.empName,e.parameter.jobName,e.parameter.taskName,e.parameter.hoursBox, e.parameter.date]; 
 runSQL("INSERT INTO "+TABLE_NAME +" (logNum,EmployeeName,JobName,TaskName,Hours,Date) VALUES (" +"'" +e.parameter.empName +"'" +"," +"'"+e.parameter.jobName +"'"+"," +"'"+e.parameter.taskName+"'" +"," +"'"+e.parameter.hoursBox+"'" +"," +"'"+e.parameter.date+"'" +")")  
}


 function runSQL(sql){

 var getDataURL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql='+sql;
 var dataResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(getDataURL,getUrlFetchOptions()).getContentText(); 
 Logger.log(dataResponse);
 return dataResponse;
}


function getUrlFetchOptions() {
var token = UserProperties.getProperty(tokenPropertyName);
Logger.log(token);
return {
"method" : "post",
"ContentType" : "application/json",
"headers":{"Authorization" :"Bearer "+token,
           "Accept" :"application/json"}


 };
}
```

Im Sure I'm missing something extremely obvious, but I've been staring for hours and can't come up with it. 
Any help, even about best practices which I have probably obliterated would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does look like you're missing some details, but don't knock yourself out. Take a look at this excellent [Fusion Tables Library](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/fusion-tables-class), which includes a function `doOAuth()` to set up the authorization for your script without making you write it all yourself.

You need to set up a ScriptProperty with the token that you've obtained - the instructions are with the library. Then call `doAuth()` from the debugger (twice), and you're ready to go.

*<sup><sub>I should be getting royalties from James F for this!</sub></sup>*

Comment: The library works, but I wanted to hard code this myself to get a better understanding of how everything works. I can't troubleshoot the library if I don't understand what it's doing. Spent another day on it today, but still missing something to bring the pieces together.

Comment: All the library source is available for download, so you can either create your own lib with it, or add it to your script. Either way, you can step through it for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Click [Here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/10UBIPSixXrD4tNTuyqxI2wbWqgaZpV22F-g5iBfY1QU/edit?usp=sharing) for a full example of the basic of POSTing to Fusion Tables API from Google apps script.